# How to pass custom parameters to jenkins job (multibranch pipeline) on git push?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, branch

I have created the multibranch pipeline and using the jenkinsfile, jenkins created set of pipelines for each branches.

Is there a way to pass custom job parameters and trigger jenkins job with bitbucket webhook?

My jenkins file has custom parameters like below example:

```
    parameters {
         string(name: "FOO", defaultValue: "bar", description: "FOO bar")
    }
```

I want to trigger the job with custom parameters during code push event.

Thank you in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your parameters in the URL.

```
http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAMETER=Value
```

Go through the [link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) for more information

Comment: The multibranch pipeline disables the ability to toggle the build parameters setting on, so this is inherently disabled in the type of jenkins config the OP referred to

Answer (score 0):

How about setting params based on commit message: (along the lines of)

```
commitMsg = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git --no-pager show -s --format='%s' -1")
```

Then in your commit you can do whatever you want, like `Finished feature. param1=this BOOL=true ...`
And in your pipeline you can parse them (not tested):

```
param1 = (commitMsg =~ /.*(param1=\S) .*]]>/)[ 0 ]​[ 1 ]
```